# Generating an 8x8 grid in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, grid

**Explination**

Through PHP I am generating an 8x8 grid of div's. The problem is not getting this to happen (Although my methods may need to change), but rather the x and y coordinates of the blocks (stored as the id).

**The Code**

```
class Grid
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $i = 0;
        $w = 'white';
        $b = 'black';
        for($y=1; $y<=8; $y++)
        {
            for($x=1; $x<=8; $x++)
            {
                if($i % 2)
                    echo "<div class='$w' id='{$x}{$y}'></div>";
                else
                    echo "<div class='$b' id='{$x}{$y}'></div>";    
                $i++;

            }
            echo "<br clear='all' /> \n";
            $i++; //offset color for next row   
        }            
    }
}
```

**Problem**

While this class does it's job of displaying the grid, the problem is the coordinates are not how I need them. The coordinates output in the following fashion because of how the HTML is rendered (imagine each bracket as the div's position on the screen):

```
note: [x coord, y coord]

[1,1] [2,1] [3,1] 
[1,2] [2,2] [3,2] 
[1,3] [2,3] [3,3]
```

I actually need the 'reverse' of this, so that it starts at the bottom left, and the coordinates resemble that of a typical grid, ie:

```
[1,3] [2,3] [3,3] 
[1,2] [2,2] [3,2] 
[1,1] [2,1] [3,1]
```

I am sure there many ways to pull this off, so the answer will go to the most elegant solution, not the fastest. Thanks!

Comment: Just say `$max_y - $y` instead of `$y`.

Comment: um, in your example, are you sure those numbers are correct? (especially 2,1 and 3,1)

Comment: That is just an example.

Comment: Although ok for small numbers, you should put a separator between the x and y numbers.  If you ever have a bigger grid, you won't be able to tell the difference between x=11, y=1 (111) and x=1, y=11 (111).  It's easy to use an underscore between them and easy to parse as well using split/explode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is as simple as changing to:

```
 for($y=8; $y>=1; $y--)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Grid
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $i = 0;
        $w = 'white';
        $b = 'black';
        for($y=8; $y>0; $y--)
        {
            for($x=1; $x<=8; $x++)
            {
                if($i % 2)
                    echo "<div class='$w' id='{$x}{$y}'></div>";
                else
                    echo "<div class='$b' id='{$x}{$y}'></div>";    
                $i++;

            }
            echo "<br clear='all' /> \n";
            $i++; //offset color for next row   
        }            
    }
}
```

and you're done

Comment: The idea behind this works however 'for($y=8; $y>2; $y--)' needs to be 'for($y=8; $y>0; $y--)'

Comment: It is. However @Frank Farmer beat yah to the same answer (and I did not have to correct it) So ill have to give it to him. +1 THOUGHT!

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for some code regarding grid building in PHP, used your
 code and changed it up...

> class Grid {
>       function __construct()
>       {
>           $i      = 0;
>           $w      = 'white';
>           $b      = 'black';
>           $y      = 1; //grid size Y
>           $y_max  = 10;
>           $x_max  = 10;
>
> ```
>     while($y <= $y_max){
>         $x      = 1; //grid size X 
>         while($x <= $x_max){
>             $color = ($i % 2 ? $w : $b);
>
>             echo "<div class='".$color."' id='{$x}{$y}'> $x , $y </div>";
>
>             $i++;
>             $x++;
>         }
>         echo "<br clear='all' /> \n";
>         $i++; //offset color for next row   
>         $y++;
>     }            
>   }
> ```
>
> }

Sorry for the formatting, I will fix the formatting later.